# Extract embed file from cropped image using steghide

Tags: command-line

I have been experimenting with `steghide` for embedding text into .jpg images.

I can embed text and then extract it using `steghide` just fine.

I have tried extracting the embedded information after slightly cropping the image, which results in:

```sh
$ steghide extract -sf myImage.jpg -xf myImage.extract.txt
Enter passphrase: 
steghide: could not extract any data with that passphrase!
```

I'm completely certain that I have the correct password.

---

Is it possible to extract at least some of this information from the cropped image? Is there an alternative tool where this is possible?
I appreciate that the more the image is cropped the less information will remain.

Could it be determined in any way that the image once had any embedded information?

Comment: Hello. I see you are asking about an app called steghide. I do not see any reference to Ubuntu in this question. Since this is an issue with this app and there is nothing that the Ubuntu OS has to do with it I have to suggest this is the wrong place to ask.

Comment: You may want to check out this site. https://www.hackingarticles.in/comprehensive-guide-to-steghide-tool/

Comment: Do you see anywhere that this **should** be possible? Does an image keep the information after editing? Anyways, I guess you need to ask the author of `steghide`.

Comment: @David I can see a number of other `steghide` questions here figured this a reasonable place to post. If you could suggest another tag to add i'll be glad to add it.

Comment: @pLumo My thought around it was that if the emedded text was small enough to be repeated multiple times in the file, then in theory a cropped version of the image would still have the full text; otherwise a partial amount of the text might still be recoverable.

Comment: A tag is not going to change the fact this has nothing to do with Ubuntu. Sorry. I gave you a link to look at.

Comment: `steghide` imposes a file structure on the low-order bits of the pixels of an image. Consider an image as a long, sequential bit string. "cropping" an image deletes large block of pixels at several places within the file structure. That's not recoverable. "He's dead, Jim".  You'll have to extract your hidden file, crop, and re-`steghide` the file in the new, cropped image.